# JS reduce issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following method inside a react component:

```
  addWidget = (index) => {
    let endX = this.state.widgets.reduce((endX, w) => endX.w + w.w, 0)

    console.log(endX);

    if (endX === 12) endX = 0

    this.setState({
      widgets: this.state.widgets.concat({
        ...this.state.availableWidgets[index],
        i: uuid(),
        x: endX,
        y: Infinity,
      })
    })
  }
```

the "addWidget" is in the render method as follow:

```
  render() {
    const { widgets } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <Button type="secondary" onClick={() => this.addWidget(0)}>Add small</Button>
        <Button type="secondary" onClick={() => this.addWidget(1)}>Add large</Button>
        <Dashboard 
          widgets={widgets} 
          onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange} 
          renderWidget={this.renderWidget} />
      </div>
    )
```

and I have the state as follow:

```
...

  state = {
    widgets: [],
    availableWidgets: [
      {
        type: 'compliance-stats',
        config: {

        },
        w: 1,
        h: 1,
      },
      {
        type: 'compliance-stats',
        config: {

        },
        w: 3,
        h: 2,
      }
    ]
  }
...
```

to start width, "this.state.widgets" is an empty array which gets populated on click with the concat method.
The first value of endX will be 0; however after that I get NaN

[image]

Comment: if your initial value is `0` then this: `endX.w` is like typing `0.w`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the initial value of the [accumulator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters) as `0`.
But you treat it like it is an object:

```
endX.w + w.w
```

it's like doing:

```
0.w + w.w
```

Which actually will do this:

```
undefined + w.w
```

This will produce `NaN`.

Try to change it to this:

```
let endX = this.state.widgets.reduce((endX, w) => endX + w.w, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your start value is 0 but you reference `endX.w` which is undefined so adding will produce `NaN`.

Let the start value be `{w:0}`